# Throttling FTP Polling consumers using apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have a requirement where in at one point of time, I need to connect to multiple ftp/sftp endpoints (say 100 ftp endpoints) to download files and process them.

I have a route like below.  The Seda queue further processes the messages by moving them into appropriate folders

```
from(ftp://username@host/foldername?password=XXXXX&include=.*).to("seda:"+routeId)
```

Now if I am starting all the FTP endpoints at the same time, which is resulting in JVM memory issues.  How could I throttle the starting of the ftp endpoints?   can I use a SEDA before the ftp to throttle (if so how can I use it)?  Any other EIP's or ideas I could use to throttle the triggering of the polling ftp consumers?

Answer (score 1):

You can look into the throttler dsl to if you want to throttle the fetching of the messages.
http://camel.apache.org/throttler.html

For controlling the startup you can look into the simplescheduleroutepolicy..
http://camel.apache.org/simplescheduledroutepolicy.html

It handles route activating and deactivating. Although I haven't used it myself but it looks like you can perhaps add a controlled delay on when routes should start and stop.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem in the past solved it using cron in the following way:

```
from("ftp://username@host/foldername?password=XXXXX&include=.*&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=0/2+*+*+*+*+?")
```

You can set up every FTP consumer to pull at different times (say with one minute difference).

If you decided to go down this path, you can use the following website to construct your crons easily:

http://www.cronmaker.com/

Hope this helps.

R.